# Big tcolorbox going out of the page, center on full paper width

Tags: positioning, tcolorbox

I'd like to have a `tcolorbox` that span all the width of my page. Do to so, I increased the size of my tcolorbox, but the problem is that it respects the margin, so it's shifted by a few cm on the right:

[image]

While I'd like more something like that:

[image]

(Nb: Here to produce the last picture, I used some tricks using overlay tikz pictures, but it's not proper, as I need to manually position all the blocks relative to each other...)

Thank you!

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
% NO EDIT
\def\cropModeCrop{crop}
\def\cropModeNocrop{nocrop} % with marks
\def\cropModeNocropmark{cropnocropmark} % without marks
\edef\currentCropMode{\cropModeNocrop} % crop, nocrop, nocropnomark

% Code to deal with crop, don't pay attention
\usepackage{eso-pic}
% Deal with trim and page geometry
% \usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage[
  showframe,
  paperwidth=297mm,
  paperheight=210mm,
  margin=5mm,
  nohead,
  nofoot,
  nomarginpar,
  pdftex=false,dvips=false,vtex=false,
]{geometry}
\newcommand{\mystockwidth}{307mm}
\newcommand{\mystockheight}{220mm}
\ifx\currentCropMode\cropModeNocrop%
\usepackage[width=\mystockwidth,height=\mystockheight,center,pdftex,frame,noinfo]{crop}
\fi
\ifx\currentCropMode\cropModeNocropmark%
\usepackage[width=\mystockwidth,height=\mystockheight,center,pdftex,noinfo]{crop}
\fi

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}%
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=\mystockwidth,halign=center]
  Hello
\end{tcolorbox}
Some text
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=\mystockwidth,halign=center]
  Hello
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
\documentclass{article}
% NO EDIT
\def\cropModeCrop{crop}
\def\cropModeNocrop{nocrop} % with marks
\def\cropModeNocropmark{cropnocropmark} % without marks
\edef\currentCropMode{\cropModeNocrop} % crop, nocrop, nocropnomark
\usepackage[
    showframe,
    paperwidth=297mm,
    paperheight=210mm,
    margin=5mm,
    nohead,
    nofoot,
    nomarginpar,
            ]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum} % <----

\begin{document}%
\lipsum[11]
\begin{adjustwidth}{-5mm}{-5mm}% <----
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=\linewidth]%\paperwidth]
\lipsum[11]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{adjustwidth}% <----
%
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=\textwidth]
  Hello
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]